# Partner Enterprise Org Expiry

Tags: environment-hub

I've created a couple of PEE orgs from my environment hub for testing. It seems they've started to expire after 1 year.

I've read somewhere that PEE are valid for 3 years. Is there a way I can extend my PEE orgs for 3 years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partner enterprise edition org's expires in 1 year, but can be extended that includes 1GB storage, and sandboxes.  You can extend by login a partner case [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388946&type=1).

[image]

Also review details on [Partner Development Org and Demo Environment](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000391959&type=1).